# SamePeriodLastYear by Day

Tags: excel, formula, powerbi, dax

I am looking to calculate the sales for the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR`. I have a table which looks at the sales for the last few years and using the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` function I can draw back to last January as a whole, but what I am wanting is to pull it to the date exactly and not to the end of the current month last year.

My formula below is pulling through for example all of January last year.

```
Sales Last Year:=CALCULATE([Sum of Sales],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Dates[Date]))
```

Is there a way of doing this using just the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` function rather than indivudual daily calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not claim that this is the best (or only) way to do this, but how about:

```
Sales Last Year =
CALCULATE (
    [Sum of Sales],
    FILTER (
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( 'Dates'[Date] ),
        'Dates'[Date]
            < DATE ( YEAR ( TODAY () ) - 1, MONTH ( TODAY () ), DAY ( TODAY () ) )
    )
)
```

Essentially, I've added a FILTER() statement around the SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR clause, and filtered the results to be before the current date last year. If today is 8-Jan-2018, this means any sales on or after 8-Jan-2017 will be filtered out.

In essence, I'm taking the current date (TODAY()), breaking it down into its component parts, subtracting 1 from the year, then building it back up into a date value using the DAX DATE() function.

The reason I do this rather than using DATEADD() to subtract a year Excel-style is because DATEADD requires a table of dates as an input and TODAY() is a single date. You therefore cannot put TODAY() into DATEADD() directly.

Instead of using TODAY(), I could have a measure that identifies the most recent date for which there is data and call that instead. It's the same solution.

I'd be curious if others have a better way to do this. This strikes me as a common problem people must run into a lot.